# How to implement custom authentication in WCF REST Service

Tags: restful-authentication

Is there any better way to implement authentication in WCF REST service which validates the user account against our database, **without using WCF Rest starter kit and Window API key**, please suggest any other better solution.
It would be helpful if you share any URL's related to the same.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated great. thanks.